# Eclipse CDT cannot debug using gdb on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project imported to Eclipse CDT. I can build and run the project using Makefile and argument settings. However, when I tried to add a debug point and run "debug as local c/c++ application", it throws me an error of `"Launching projectName" has encountered a problem. Error with command gdb --version`
By expanding the Details, it gives: `Error with command: gdb --version
Cannot run program "gdb": Unknown reason`

I installed the gdb by Macports before. If I enter command `ggdb` it returns the version info. If I type `which ggdb`, it gives `/opt/local/bin/ggdb`. I tried to add "PATH" to debug configuration -> environment variables and give the path value to it, but it did not work. How should I set the path and link the path please? And what should the variable name be.

The gdb version on my machine is GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1

Added: I looked up `which ggdb` and used the link James provided to change gdb debugger to browse to that path. But it did not work still. 
[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: What version of gdb are you using?

Comment: @JamesMoore : GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1 Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse is using the default `gdb` that was on the system before you installed `ggdb` from macports. This [link](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_dsfgdb.htm) shows how to change the debugger settings, change it to `ggdb` which is the name Macport uses.

After installing `ggdb` from Macports you will have to sign it with a certificate so it will be allowed to control other processes, take a look at "Certifying GDB" [here](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/). After creating the certificate, make sure you select the correct name when signing:

```
$ codesign -s gdb-cert $(which ggdb) /// 'ggdb'
```

Comment: Did you try the full path `/opt/local/bin/ggdb`?

Comment: I did, but the same error still comes. Please see the edited screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: @user2751691 Updated with a link showing how to sign `ggdb` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks like the trick. But there were commands that require permission so I used `sudo`, now if I debug it, it gives: No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Comment: @user2751691 Check that you are running the debug build of your application, not the release through gdb. The debug build should have the option `-g` or `-ggdb` when compiling (eg. `g++ -ggdb projectName.cpp -o prog`). Then run that binary through `gdb`.

Comment: I modified my makefile, I made it to  `test: $(SIMPLE_CLIENT)
 g++ -ggdb -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib $(SIMPLE_CLIENT) -o simple_client -lodbc` Would this be in right format? The -L is with the libraries I need to compile my project. Thank you.

Comment: Now it does not throw an error, but gives no output, and the progress keeps at 99%... I have to force quit to quit eclipse, lol

Comment: Hi James, just to give u an update. Looks like the problem is from the certificate codesigning. I had the a typo to the name of the certificate, and to make it perfect, I deleted it and added a new one. Somehow the ggdb keeps thinking it has already been code-signed and refuses to accept the new link. Then I reinstalled my machine, did code-signing at one shot, and then it worked...