# run valgrind/other memory-checks through eclipse luna in Windows-8 64bit

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to run a c++ project in eclipse with valgrind leak check.
I can't see the output of valgrind in eclipse console, therefore I can't know if I have leaks or not.

I added in *run configurations --> arguments* the following:
 **valgrind --leak-check=yes**

Do I need to add anything? Is there a different reason that might cause this?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**
The problem is with Valgrind not running on Windows. I used to work in Linux environment and didn't know Windows doesn't work with Valgrind in the same way.

So rephrasing my question:

I am using **Eclipse Luna** on **Windows 8 64bit**.

I have looked through some other posts but so far nothing has been working:

**1**. I tried to get the Visual Leak Detector, but I couldn't debug because of gdb problems (I installed it using *apt-get* command).
I tried to:
**A**.  set the location of my gdb, like here [Eclipse CDT cannot debug using gdb on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357136/eclipse-cdt-cannot-debug-using-gdb-on-mac) but couldn't understand it's location in windows (*find . -name* returned no interesting results).
 **B**.  Also I tried to set the *Source Lookup Path* as mentioned here [How to get gdb working with Eclipse CDT under windows (fails to find source code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267632/how-to-get-gdb-working-with-eclipse-cdt-under-windows-fails-to-find-source-code) , but it did not work as well.
**C**.  Also I tried to reinstall cygwin and select the gdb package, but it was N/A (or I at least couldn't understand how to select it).

**2**. I tried this from [Free Application to check Memory Leaks in Windows x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235858/free-application-to-check-memory-leaks-in-windows-x64)

*#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC*
*#include* 
*#include*

Add the following right before the program's exit point(s):

*_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();*

It doesn't work as well.

I will try and get the other tools in other posts when I have the time, but if anyone has a solution for why what I have tried so far didn't work - I'll be happy to know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the plugin?

Try out this link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the problem is that Valgrind is not supported in Windows, so i'm looking for other options.