# eclipse debug not work

Tags: c, eclipse

i use eclipse to run c language program

after build project,it print

> Building target: testusb Invoking: Cross GCC Linker gcc
> -L/opt/local/lib -lusb-1.0 -o "testusb"  ./src/testusb.o    Finished building target: testusb
>
> 14:44:40 Build Finished (took 120ms)
>
> 14:44:49 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
> testusb **** make all  make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>
> 14:44:49 Build Finished (took 68ms)
>
> 14:45:10 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
> testusb **** make all  make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>
> 14:45:10 Build Finished (took 65ms)

in terminal when i cd the directory and type testusb,it print success.

[image]

but when i debug use eclipse,it not print success and cannot step into main breakpoint.
[image]

the debug configure is
[image]
[image]

the project structure is
[image]
the program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
int main(void) {
    libusb_context **libcontext;
    libusb_device ***deviceList;
    int status = libusb_init(libcontext);
    if (status == 0) {
//      libusb_get_device_list(*libcontext,deviceList);
        printf("success");
    }
```

}

my question is why debug cannot step into breakpoint and cannot print success?

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason is eclipse default support gdb,but mac is ggdb.i try the solution [Eclipse CDT cannot debug using gdb on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357136/eclipse-cdt-cannot-debug-using-gdb-on-mac)
but  apple-gcc42 is not supported on OS X versions newer than El Capitan,my mac is macos sierra

i change xcode 
[image]

i add [image]
[image]

it can debug!
[image]

reference [Linking Libraries in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode)

[ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358591/xcode-library-not-found)